# MemCache, Rails, pages showing different data at different times

Tags: ruby-on-rails, memcached, thinking-sphinx

We've got a strange problem that is very hard to troubleshoot.  We are looking for some assistance on methods that might help us troubleshoot this problem.  We use memcache and thinksphinx.  Recently we moved to a new server and suddenly elements on the pages are showing up missing.

So for instance, our home page has news items and latest files added.  In one case I see that we are missing the last 2 news items.  My developer checks and sees its there.  10 minutes later he checks and see all the news items missing.  Check again 15 minutes later and missing 3 items.

We were able to notice that on the server move we had memcache set at 2mb, so we moved it up to 1gb.  It looked like everything was fixed.  However, now we are seeing similar inconsistencies when people are searching.  Users will report problems, I will see them, send them to my developer and he sees different results.  We both refresh and see something else.

We are able to realize this is somehow related to memcache and/or our thinkingsphinx, because when we clear and rebuild, everything acts normal.

My only assumption is that at some point we run out of memory in memcache, but it makes no sense that only certain data would not be shown.

Can anyone give any advice?

Thanks,
Will